# How to Install devtoolset 8 in RHEL 8 image

Tags: rhel8

Please help me to install dev toolset-8 in rhel 8 image.

i have pulled the base image as below . I want to install devtoolset-8. is there any other way please let me know.

sudo docker pull registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi:8.2

Answer (score 4):

`devtoolset` is called `gcc-toolset` in `RHEL8`.

The following commands worked for me:

```
microdnf install -y gcc-toolset-12
scl enable gcc-toolset-12 bash
gcc --version
# gcc (GCC) 12.1.1 20220628 (Red Hat 12.1.1-3)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [that article](https://developers.redhat.com/products/developertoolset/hello-world), you can check if you have access to [Red Hat Software Collections](https://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/) (RHSCL) by running the following command by the root user:

```
$ su -
# subscription-manager repos --list | egrep rhscl
```

If you have, enable necessary software repo and then install devtoolset:

```
# subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-7-server-optional-rpms
# yum install devtoolset-8
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer seems to be for RHEL 7.

On the [RedHat site](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/4454491)

Chrisian Labisch answered this with:

> RHEL 8 doesn't work with Software Collections, RHEL 8 uses modules instead.
>
> `sudo dnf module list`
>
> In RHEL 8 you find the developer tools in the CodeReady Builder repository. :)
>
> `sudo subscription-manager repos --enable codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms`

But even that seems to be unneeded because the system compiler version for RHEL is already GCC 8, so you would normally only need devtoolset-9 or up for it, if I understood the purpose correctly.

Additionally [this blog post](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/11/15/rhel8-introducing-appstreams) outlines the differences between the old SCL toolsets and the new AppStreams concept.