Compilation failed when installing Rcpp on RHEL8
When I try to install R Package Rcpp I got following ERROR Message.
> install.packages("Rcpp")
Installing package into ‘/<SOMEDIR>/r/lib_user’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://packages.othr.de/cran/src/contrib/Rcpp_1.0.11.tar.gz'
Content type 'text/plain' length 2994004 bytes (2.9 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.9 MB

* installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
** package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
using C++ compiler: ‘g++ (GCC) 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-22)’
g++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection   -c api.cpp -o api.o
In file included from ../inst/include/Rcpp/routines.h:26,
                 from ../inst/include/RcppCommon.h:128,
                 from ../inst/include/Rcpp.h:27,
                 from api.cpp:26:
../inst/include/Rcpp/iostream/Rstreambuf.h: In member function ‘std::streamsize Rcpp::Rstreambuf<OUTPUT>::xsputn(const char*, std::streamsize) [with bool OUTPUT = true; std::streamsize = long int]’:
../inst/include/Rcpp/iostream/Rstreambuf.h:53:17: warning: field precision specifier ‘.*’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘std::streamsize’ {aka ‘long int’} [-Wformat=]
         Rprintf("%.*s", num, s);
                 ^~~~~~  ~~~
../inst/include/Rcpp/iostream/Rstreambuf.h: In member function ‘std::streamsize Rcpp::Rstreambuf<OUTPUT>::xsputn(const char*, std::streamsize) [with bool OUTPUT = false; std::streamsize = long int]’:
../inst/include/Rcpp/iostream/Rstreambuf.h:57:18: warning: field precision specifier ‘.*’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘std::streamsize’ {aka ‘long int’} [-Wformat=]
         REprintf("%.*s", num, s);
                  ^~~~~~  ~~~
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppCommon.h:181,
                 from ../inst/include/Rcpp.h:27,
                 from api.cpp:26:
../inst/include/Rcpp/print.h: In function ‘void Rcpp::warningcall(SEXP, const string&)’:
../inst/include/Rcpp/print.h:30:35: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
     Rf_warningcall(call, s.c_str());
                                   ^
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf:204: api.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’
* removing ‘/<SOMEDIR>/r/lib_user/Rcpp’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpEIOeWD/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("Rcpp") :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status


I have installed the following R, make and gcc version.
$ R --version
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24) -- "Puppy Cup"
Copyright (C) 2024 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
For more information about these matters see
https://www.gnu.org/licenses/.

$ make --version
make: getcwd: No such file or directory
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-22)
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Does anyone have any idea why the installation fails? If any configs are interesting I can provide them as well.
I have already tried to restore the Renviron.rpmnew config. The same problem occurs here too.
Enclosed is the makeconf
# etc/Makeconf.  Generated from Makeconf.in by configure.
#
# ${R_HOME}/etc/Makeconf
#
# R was configured using the following call
# (not including env. vars and site configuration)
# configure  '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' 'rdocdir=/usr/share/doc/R' 'rincludedir=/usr/include/R' 'rsharedir=/usr/share/R' '--with-system-tre' '--with-blas=openblaso' '--with-lapack' '--with-tcl-config=/usr/lib64/tclConfig.sh' '--with-tk-config=/usr/lib64/tkConfig.sh' '--enable-R-shlib' '--enable-prebuilt-html' '--enable-R-profiling' '--enable-memory-profiling' 'build_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'R_BROWSER=/usr/bin/xdg-open' 'R_PDFVIEWER=/usr/bin/xdg-open' 'JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre' 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH=:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig' 'CFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-z,relro  -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld' 'FCFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules' 'CXXFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection'

## This fails if it contains spaces, or if it is quoted
include $(R_SHARE_DIR)/make/vars.mk

AR = ar
BLAS_LIBS = -lopenblaso

## C compilers
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection $(LTO)
CC17 = gcc -std=gnu17
C17FLAGS = -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection $(LTO)
CC23 = 
C23FLAGS =  $(LTO)
CC90 = gcc -std=gnu90
C90FLAGS = -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection $(LTO)
CC99 = gcc -std=gnu99
C99FLAGS = -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection $(LTO)
CPICFLAGS = -fpic
CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/include
C_VISIBILITY = -fvisibility=hidden

## C++ compilers
CXX = g++ -std=gnu++17
CXXFLAGS = -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection $(LTO)
CXXPICFLAGS = -fpic
CXX11 = g++
CXX11FLAGS = -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection $(LTO)
CXX11PICFLAGS = -fpic
CXX11STD = -std=gnu++11
CXX14 = g++
CXX14FLAGS = -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection $(LTO)
CXX14PICFLAGS = -fpic
CXX14STD = -std=gnu++14
CXX17 = g++
CXX17FLAGS = -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection $(LTO)
CXX17PICFLAGS = -fpic
CXX17STD = -std=gnu++17
CXX20 = 
CXX20FLAGS =  $(LTO)
CXX20PICFLAGS = 
CXX20STD = 
CXX23 = 
CXX23FLAGS =  $(LTO)
CXX23PICFLAGS = 
CXX23STD = 
CXX_VISIBILITY = -fvisibility=hidden

DYLIB_EXT = .so
DYLIB_LD = $(CC)
DYLIB_LDFLAGS = -shared -fopenmp# $(CFLAGS) $(CPICFLAGS) 
## should be used by packages for dylibs, but at the time of writing was not
DYLIB_LINK = $(DYLIB_LD) $(DYLIB_LDFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
ECHO = echo
ECHO_C = 
ECHO_N = -n
ECHO_T = 

## Fortran
FC = gfortran
FCFLAGS = -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules $(LTO_FC)
## additional libs needed when linking with $(FC), e.g. on some Oracle compilers
FCLIBS_XTRA = 
FFLAGS = -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules $(LTO_FC)
FLIBS =  -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath
FPICFLAGS = -fpic
FPIEFLAGS = -fPIE
F_VISIBILITY = -fvisibility=hidden

FOUNDATION_CPPFLAGS = 
FOUNDATION_LIBS = 
JAR = /usr/bin/jar
JAVA = /usr/bin/java
JAVAC = /usr/bin/javac
JAVAH = /usr/bin/javah
## JAVA_HOME might be used in the next three.  
## They are for packages 'JavaGD' and 'rJava'
JAVA_HOME = /usr/lib/jvm/jre
JAVA_CPPFLAGS = -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/linux
JAVA_LIBS = -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH = $(JAVA_HOME)/lib/amd64/server
LAPACK_LIBS = 
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-z,relro  -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld
## we only need this is if it is external, as otherwise link to R
LIBINTL= 
LIBM = -lm
LIBR0 = -L"$(R_HOME)/lib$(R_ARCH)"
LIBR1 = -lR
LIBR = -L"$(R_HOME)/lib$(R_ARCH)" -lR
LIBS =  -ltre -lpcre2-8 -llzma -lbz2 -lz -ltirpc -lrt -ldl -lm -licuuc -licui18n
## needed by R CMD config
LIBnn = lib64
LIBTOOL = $(SHELL) "$(R_HOME)/bin/libtool"
## set for --enable-lto, --enable-lto=check
LTO = 
LTO_FC = 
LTO_LD = 
## set for --enable-lto=R, used in INSTALL
LTO_OPT = 
LTO_FC_OPT = 
## needed to build applications linking to static libR
MAIN_LD = $(CC)
MAIN_LDFLAGS = -Wl,--export-dynamic -fopenmp
MAIN_LINK = $(MAIN_LD) $(MAIN_LDFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
MKINSTALLDIRS = "$(R_HOME)/bin/mkinstalldirs"
NM = /usr/bin/nm -B
OBJC = 
OBJCFLAGS =  $(LTO)
OBJC_LIBS = 
OBJCXX = 
R_ARCH = 
RANLIB = ranlib
SAFE_FFLAGS = -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules -msse2 -mfpmath=sse
## A version of SHLIB_LIBADD not overridden in install.R.
SAN_LIBS =
SED = /usr/bin/sed
SHELL = /bin/sh
SHLIB_CFLAGS = 
SHLIB_CXXFLAGS = 
SHLIB_CXXLD = $(CXX)
SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS = -shared# $(CXXFLAGS) $(CXXPICFLAGS) $(LTO_LD)
SHLIB_CXX11LD = $(CXX11) $(CXX11STD)
SHLIB_CXX11LDFLAGS = -shared# $(CXX11FLAGS) $(CXX11PICFLAGS) $(LTO_LD)
SHLIB_CXX14LD = $(CXX14) $(CXX14STD)
SHLIB_CXX14LDFLAGS = -shared# $(CXX14FLAGS) $(CXX14PICFLAGS) $(LTO_LD)
SHLIB_CXX17LD = $(CXX17) $(CXX17STD)
SHLIB_CXX17LDFLAGS = -shared# $(CXX17FLAGS) $(CXX17PICFLAGS) $(LTO_LD)
SHLIB_CXX20LD = $(CXX20) $(CXX20STD)
SHLIB_CXX20LDFLAGS = -shared# $(CXX20FLAGS) $(CXX20PICFLAGS) $(LTO_LD)
SHLIB_CXX23LD = $(CXX23) $(CXX23STD)
SHLIB_CXX23LDFLAGS = -shared# $(CXX23FLAGS) $(CXX23PICFLAGS) $(LTO_LD)
SHLIB_EXT = .so
SHLIB_FCLD = $(FC)
SHLIB_FCLDFLAGS = -shared# $(FCFLAGS) $(FPICFLAGS)
SHLIB_FFLAGS = 
SHLIB_LD = $(CC)
## used for add-on packages linked by C
SHLIB_LDFLAGS = -shared# $(CFLAGS) $(CPICFLAGS) $(LTO_LD)
## used for standard packages
SHLIB_LDFLAGS_R = -shared# $(CFLAGS) $(CPICFLAGS) $(LTO_LD)
## used in install.R to add OBJC_LIBS, FLIBS ....
SHLIB_LIBADD = 
## We want to ensure libR is picked up from $(R_HOME)/lib
## before e.g. /usr/local/lib if a version is already installed.
SHLIB_LINK = $(SHLIB_LD) $(SHLIB_LDFLAGS) $(LIBR0) $(LDFLAGS)
SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS = -fopenmp
SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS = -fopenmp
SHLIB_OPENMP_FFLAGS = -fopenmp
STRIP_STATIC_LIB = strip --strip-debug
STRIP_SHARED_LIB = strip --strip-unneeded
TCLTK_CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/include -I/usr/include 
TCLTK_LIBS = -L/usr/lib64 -ltcl8.6 -L/usr/lib64 -ltk8.6 -lX11
YACC = yacc

## for linking to libR.a
STATIC_LIBR = # -Wl,--whole-archive "$(R_HOME)/lib$(R_ARCH)/libR.a" -Wl,--no-whole-archive $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)  $(LIBINTL) -lreadline  $(LIBS)

## These are recorded as macros for legacy use in packages
## set on AIX, formerly for old glibc (-D__NO_MATH_INLINES)
R_XTRA_CFLAGS = 
##  was formerly set on HP-UX
R_XTRA_CPPFLAGS =  -I"$(R_INCLUDE_DIR)" -DNDEBUG
## currently unset
R_XTRA_CXXFLAGS = 
## used for gfortran >= 7 in R 3.6.1 - 4.2.x
R_XTRA_FFLAGS = 

## SHLIB_CFLAGS SHLIB_CXXFLAGS SHLIB_FFLAGS are apparently currently unused
## SHLIB_CXXFLAGS is undocumented, there is no SHLIB_FCFLAGS
ALL_CFLAGS =  $(PKG_CFLAGS) $(CPICFLAGS) $(SHLIB_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)
## XDEFS was a temporary measure for use by R CMD INSTALL
ALL_CPPFLAGS =  -I"$(R_INCLUDE_DIR)" -DNDEBUG $(PKG_CPPFLAGS) $(CLINK_CPPFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS)  $(XDEFS)
## CXX_DEFS allows adding defines only for C++, e.g. -DR_NO_REMAP
ALL_CXXFLAGS =  $(PKG_CXXFLAGS) $(CXXPICFLAGS) $(SHLIB_CXXFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CXX_DEFS)
ALL_OBJCFLAGS = $(PKG_OBJCFLAGS) $(CPICFLAGS) $(SHLIB_CFLAGS) $(OBJCFLAGS)
ALL_OBJCXXFLAGS = $(PKG_OBJCXXFLAGS) $(CXXPICFLAGS) $(SHLIB_CXXFLAGS) $(OBJCXXFLAGS)
ALL_FFLAGS =  $(PKG_FFLAGS) $(FPICFLAGS) $(SHLIB_FFLAGS) $(FFLAGS)
## can be overridden by R CMD SHLIB
P_FCFLAGS = $(PKG_FFLAGS)
ALL_FCFLAGS =  $(P_FCFLAGS) $(FPICFLAGS) $(SHLIB_FFLAGS) $(FCFLAGS)
## LIBR here as a couple of packages use this without SHLIB_LINK
ALL_LIBS = $(PKG_LIBS) $(SHLIB_LIBADD) $(SAN_LIBS) $(LIBR)# $(LIBINTL)

.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .c .cc .cpp .d .f .f90 .f95 .m .mm .M .o

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
.c.d:
    @echo "making $@ from $<"
    @$(CC) -MM $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $< > $@
.m.d:
    @echo > $@
.cc.o:
    $(CXX) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
.cc.d:
    @echo "making $@ from $<"
    @$(CXX) -M $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $< > $@
.cpp.d:
    @echo "making $@ from $<"
    @$(CXX) -M $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $< > $@
.m.o:
    $(OBJC) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_OBJCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
.mm.o:
    $(OBJCXX) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_OBJCXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
.M.o:
    $(OBJCXX) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_OBJCXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
.f.o:
    $(FC) $(ALL_FFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
.f95.o:
    $(FC) $(ALL_FCFLAGS) -c  $< -o $@
.f90.o:
    $(FC) $(ALL_FCFLAGS) -c  $< -o $@


You likely need a newer compiler than gcc-8 / g++-8 which you can get from something called devtoolset. See eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70155008/how-to-install-devtoolset-8-in-rhel-8-image

It is fixed in the 1.0.13 https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/releases/tag/1.0.13

@AdaLovelace I've tried that using gcc-toolset-12 with g++ (GCC) 12.2.1 20221121 (Red Hat 12.2.1-7) but the problem still occurs.

@LorinczyZsigmond - Do you have any idea when the fix will be distributed via the usual CRAN servers?

No, but you might try to remove this bit: -Werror=format-security from Makeconf* files

@ChristopherGies As was observedm you used an old version release July of last year.  Version 1.0.13 is current and came out this year, see https://cloud.r-project.org/package=Rcpp and try that one.
